# How do I prevent additional jobs from a given user from starting?

Tags: batch-processing, slurm

With the Slurm workload manager how can I prevent more jobs from user `bob` from starting? Existing jobs should continue to run. The user should be able to submit more jobs but they shouldn't be able to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slurm's `sacctmgr` command can be used to modify various limits per user. You need to be an account coordinator for the account in question or root. Setting either one of these to `0` should do the trick:

- `MaxJobs`
- `GrpJobs`

As an example:

```
$ sacctmgr modify user where name=bob set MaxJobs=0
```

After a few minutes if you run `squeue` on the user you should see something like this:

```
$ squeue -u bob -o "%i %r"
JOBID REASON
20582420 AssocMaxJobsLimit
20583282 Dependency
```

Note that the `Dependency` reason seems to take precedence over the user limits, but it won't run anyway because it is waiting for the other job to run. Similarly `JobArrayTaskLimit` will take precedence over the user limits but the job won't start.

To remove the limit set the value to `-1`:

```
$ sacctmgr modify user where name=bob set MaxJobs=-1
```

---

You can show the existing limits for a user with:

```
$ sacctmgr list assoc User=bob
```